# Osmdroid Marker and Json Android

Tags: android, osmdroid

I am working with osmdroid library and android http request. So what I am doing is populating a map with markers where the lat and long are obtained from a database on the server. The question id: How can I call to marker.setOnClickListener out of the method where I do the request. 
Here's my code:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        try {


                            JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(response);
                            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject primer = obj.getJSONObject(i);                                   

                                double latitud = primer.getDouble(TAG_Latitud);
                                double longitude = primer.getDouble(TAG_Longitude);

                                marker = new Marker(map);
                                marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(latitud, longitude));
                                marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);


                                mHashMap.put(marker, i);
                                Terrenos.add(terrenos);

                            }

                            marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Osmdroid.this, Activity2.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            map.getOverlays().add(marker);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(Osmdroid.this,"Something Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.w("exception", e.toString());
                        }



                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(Osmdroid.this,"Something Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.w("Error", "No hay respuesta en http");


            }
        });


        queue.add(stringRequest);



    }
```

So, in the code above I create the marker inside the 'for', and I am calling the onClick method when it finished. But when I do this not all the marker works when on click, only the last one created.
Does somebody knows what to do? Please, I really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last marker has onClick because you set it just to it.
in every looping, the marker object gets a new reference `marker = new Marker(map);`. Because of that at the last looping, the marker object contains the last references and the onClick method sets just to it.

To solve that you just need to set the `onClick`and the `map.getOverlays().add(marker)` inside the loop.

```
  public void onResponse(String response) {
    try {


        JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject primer = obj.getJSONObject(i);                                   

            double latitud = primer.getDouble(TAG_Latitud);
            double longitude = primer.getDouble(TAG_Longitude);

            marker = new Marker(map);
            marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(latitud, longitude));
            marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);

            map.getOverlays().add(marker);

            mHashMap.put(marker, i);
            Terrenos.add(terrenos);

            marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Osmdroid.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });


        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. And Sorry If I wasn't clear. But I am still confused about the answer. In my code I create the marker through the lat and long data that obtained from server in the onResponse. I dont understand how to create and show markers on the map, from the method above.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain in details, what are you doing wrong, because it seems that you are missing some basics about OOP programing, variables etc.

**What's wrong**:

You create multiple objects of type Marker in your loop, but variable named `marker` stores a reference to only one object of type Marker. You are reusing this variable in you loop end during each iteration you assign another instance of class Marker (another object of type Marker, with its own personal chunk of memory).

Once the loop finishes, your variable still exists and points to one object -  and it's the last one Marker instance created, because it was the last value assigned to the variable named `marker`. You are assigning OnMarkerClickListener to this one and only object.

**How to fix it**
You want to call method `setOnMarkerClickListener` (assign OnMarkerClickListener) on every instance of Marker you have created. The way to do it is the same as with the creation: use a loop. You have basically 2 options here:

1) Reuse loop which is already in code and assign listener there. It's the simplest solution, because you can just move the assignment a little bit up in your source code and it would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject primer = obj.getJSONObject(i);                                   

    double latitud = primer.getDouble(TAG_Latitud);
    double longitude = primer.getDouble(TAG_Longitude);

    marker = new Marker(map);
    marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(latitud, longitude));
    marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);


    mHashMap.put(marker, i);
    Terrenos.add(terrenos);

    marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Osmdroid.this, Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

map.getOverlays().add(marker);
```

This is not the most optimal way how to do it though. There is new instance of listener created for each marker, so a little bit of memory is wasted. But you can create an instance of listener before loop, store it in variable and assign the same object to all markers. Try to figure it out as an improvement, once you get things working.

2) You can store markers somewhere and create another loop where you'll assign the listener(s). You can have an variable (or a field in your class) containing list of all markers

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
```

In loop, once a marker is created you can add it to this list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {

    ...  

    marker = new Marker(map);
    marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(latitud, longitude));
    marker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);

    markers.add(marker); //addind to the listt

    ...
```

Than you can iterate over the list later and assign listener to all of markers. Try to figure the code yourself. There will be similar decision as in previous case: you can create new listener for each marker or reuse one for all of them.

And the last thing: you don't need to craete new variable with list as I mentioned above, because you already have field which contains all your markers. You are using them as keys in a hasmmap:

```
mHashMap.put(marker, i);
```

I don't know what is a purpose of this hashmap, but you can get access to all markers (exactly: to an instance of [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) with all markers) via `mHasnMap.keySet()`

Comment: Thank you for your replay and your detailed explanation. I looked again on my code and found some wrong coding, as the hashmap. I created another method where I add the markers on the map and a loop with the list of markers where I call to onCLickListener for each markers.
Thank you for your help.